# Fitting a table within the text

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to create a table for my first appendix but I am facing the two following problems:

- I would like to align the text of the first column to the left.
- The columns are not equally distributed along the width of the text.

I show you here the code I am using and the result of it:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\appendix
\section{Suppliers´ production capacities}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ccL@{}}
\toprule
Facility Name & Year & Overall Capacity \\
\midrule
Text    & 2020                              & 1.500                                                    \\
Text   & 2020                              & 1.600                                                    \\
Text          & 2020                              & 2.500                                                    \\
                               
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  \caption{Supplier facilities´ production capacities}
\end{table}
```

[image]
I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me with this

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}LLL@{}}`should fulfill both requirements. However, I would not recommend artifically stretching a narrow table to the textwidth as the added white space does not increase readability. `\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}` should be sufficient here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to align the text of the first column to the left.

Just change

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ccL@{}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lcL@{}}
```

> The columns are not equally distributed along the width of the text.

How about

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}LLL@{}}
```

i.e., use the `L` column type for all three columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} LLL @{}}
\toprule
Facility Name & Year & Overall Capacity \\
\midrule
Text & 2020 & 1.500  \\
Text & 2020 & 1.600  \\
Text & 2020 & 2.500  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Supplier facilities' production capacities}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```